# Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword NEW at [2:93]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Can anyone help with how I need to change my query please? I am new to BigQuery

```
  with W as (
        select COALESCE(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(startTime) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAG(startTime, 1) over UW) > 1000, 1) new
             , W.startTime
             , W.id
             , W.user
        from Workout W
        window UW AS (partition by W.user order by W.startTime)
    )
    select SUM(new) OVER (order by W.user, W.startTime) pseudoSession
         , W.id
         , W.startTime
         , W.user
    from W;
```

Comment: `new` is a reserved word ... are you trying to use `new` as a column alias?

Comment: ah yes i was, schoolboy error. Thanks. Now I have changed that I am now getting this 

No matching signature for function COALESCE for argument types: BOOL, INT64.

Comment: @PaulT., can you post your answer in the Answer section of StackOverflow so that the community can easily find the solution to OP's question.

Comment: The `BOOL` portion is because of the long calculation as the first parameter to the `COALESCE` that ultimately ends with the `> 1000`. I'm not 100% sure, but it seems like maybe the entire first parameter from before the first `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` to just after the 1000 needs to be within another set of `()`?

Answer (score 1):

As `new` is a [reserved keyword](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#reserved_keywords), you likely meant to do:

```
with W as (
    select COALESCE(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(startTime) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAG(startTime, 1) over UW) > 1000, 1) `new`
         , W.startTime
         , W.id
         , W.user
    from Workout W
    window UW AS (partition by W.user order by W.startTime)
)
select SUM(new) OVER (order by W.user, W.startTime) pseudoSession
     , W.id
     , W.startTime
     , W.user
from W;
```

Alternatively, some other non-reserved word can be used as well.